# Are there any issues with a large boot partition?

Tags: linux, partition, boot

[What is the recommended size for a Linux /boot partition?](https://serverfault.com/questions/334663/what-is-the-recommended-size-for-a-linux-boot-partition/334665) says the recommended size for a boot partition is about 300-500MB, which is congruent with my experience (running out of space with < 300MBs). Aside from potentially wasting disk space, is there any problem with something like a 2GB boot partition? Sorry if this is a bit off topic, I'm not quite sure which site this should go on.

Comment: RHEL 8 now creates 1GB /boot partitions by default. This seems reasonable. The kernel isn't getting smaller, after all. See my answer on the question you linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your boot partition can be as large as your filesystem allows (at least I'm not aware about any limitations in grub2 in standard distros like Debian based or CentOS/RHEL based), 2GB is fine as well depends how many previous kernels you want to keep. I'm usually using 1GB but when I'm trying custom kernel builds to keep more previous kernel version, just add more 4-10GB is usually enough. But I've never tried i.e. 4TB large boot partition, so is possible there is a limit.